# Border Color Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Is there any way to make a border 2 colors through Tailwind? I am trying to make a black and white top border, but it won't let me use a gradient since those are just for backgrounds

I tried using the CSS method of having a small container and giving the outside container a gradient color but I was wondering if there was a more intuitive way to just apply the linear gradient to the border itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the small container wrapper around the big container is the normal solution for this. There is not necessarily a better way to do it even when using plain CSS other than possibly using the 'border-image' property, but then it eliminates the possibility of using the 'border-radius' property.

**Below** is the simple solution, that it seems you have seen before:

```
<div class="min-w-screen flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center bg-slate-500">
  <div class="w-fit bg-gradient-to-r from-black to-white pb-2 pt-2 rounded-sm">
    <div class="content h-48 w-48 bg-orange-200 text-center">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```